# Do all GA accounts have "All Web Site Data" view ID to track and summarize all the view IDs?

Tags: google-analytics, google-api

In google analytics, there is a view ID called **"All Web Site Data"**. I am trying to show a summary of data by pulling it from google analytics via the google API into a third-party website dashboard. Can anybody explain about this view ID?

Answer (score 0):

When you log into your Google analytics Universal account.  You can create accounts each account is connected for example to a website.  Under that you have a web property Under that is a view or profile.

A view is where the data is collected. A view is where you look at the data, it displayed hits from the property. You can have more then one view and filter them differently.